# Problema para resolver consulta a MySql PHP if, else, echo,

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo esta tabla en MySql con fechas **No disponibles** y horas **No disponibles** en la agenda de un doctor. Al hacer una consulta debo mostrar los horarios que si se encuentran disponibles y bloquear los que no están diponibles.

- id | id_doc |    fecha    |   hora   |
- 1  |   4    |  24-07-2019 |   8:00   |
- 1  |   4    |  24-07-2019 |   9:00   |
- 1  |   4    |  24-07-2019 |  10:00   |
- 1  |   4    |  24-07-2019 |  11:00   |

Si utilizo un if(empty(variable)){echo}else{echo} solo me está mostrando el segundo echo, en el primero no arroja ningún resultado. Cuando le pregunto por una fecha que no está en la base de datos, por ejemplo si pregunto para el día 30, que no existe en la tabla, no me arroja nada

No me quiero encerrar solo en esta opción, si alguien me pudiera ayudar con algo de logística o corregir el error en mi código bienvenido será!!!

```
                        <?php 
                                $id_doc=$_POST['id'];
                                $datos=$_POST['datos'];

                                $res=("SELECT * FROM reservas WHERE (fecha = '$datos') and (id_doc = '$id_doc') ");
                                $reserva = mysqli_query($con,$res) or mysqli_error($con);
                                while($horas = mysqli_fetch_array($reserva)) {
                                if (empty($horas['fecha'])){ echo '8:00','9:00','10:00','11:00';}else{echo $horas['hora'];}

                                    }
 ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola dado que en tu tabla tienes las horas **No Disponibles**, debes crear una tabla donde guardes las horas, recuerda LAS FORMAS NORMALES.

Tendré una tabla donde esta el calendario de horas que pueden ser ocupadas.

```
 TABLA CALENDARIO
     id  hora    
------  --------
     1  08:00   
     2  09:00   
     3  10:00   
     4  11:00   
     5  12:00   
     6  14:00   
     7  15:00
```

Luego tendré en la tabla de reservas

```
    TABLA RESERVAS
    id     id_doctor  fecha       hora    
  ------  ---------  ----------  --------
     1          1    2019-07-21   1      ---> RELACIÓN A 8:00 
     2          2    2019-07-22   2      ---> RELACIÓN A 9:00  
     3          2    2019-07-21   1      ---> RELACIÓN A 8:00
```

Así ahora solo tendré que consultar el calendario de horas que no se encuentren en reserva ( lógico no! )

```sql
    SELECT DISTINCT horas.hora FROM horas
    JOIN reservas ON reservas.hora != horas.id
    WHERE id_doctor = 1
```

Repuesta

```
     hora    
    --------
    09:00   
    10:00   
    11:00   
    12:00   
    14:00
```

Incluso por fecha

```sql
    SELECT DISTINCT horas.hora FROM horas
    JOIN reservas ON reservas.hora != horas.id
    WHERE id_doctor =  2 AND fecha = '2019-07-22'
```

No esta disponible el 9:00

```sql
   hora    
 --------
  08:00   
  10:00   
  11:00   
  12:00   
  14:00
```

Por ultimo solo las horas ocupadas en `reservas.hora = horas.id`.

```sql
    SELECT DISTINCT horas.hora FROM horas
    JOIN reservas ON reservas.hora = horas.id
    WHERE id_doctor =  2 AND fecha = '2019-07-22'
```

```sql
    hora    
  --------
    09:00
```

Espero esto te ayude.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que propone Diego Mesa está bien pero en caso de tener dos reservas para el mismo doctor el mismo día no te daría bien las horas libres.

Ejemplo:
Si tenemos estas reservas

```
   id     id_doctor  fecha       hora    
 ------  ---------  ----------  --------
    1          1    2019-07-21   1      ---> RELACIÓN A 8:00 
    2          2    2019-07-22   2      ---> RELACIÓN A 9:00  
    3          2    2019-07-21   1      ---> RELACIÓN A 8:00
    4          2    2019-07-21   2      ---> RELACIÓN A 9:00
```

Y realizamos la consulta de horas disponibles por fecha

```
SELECT DISTINCT horas.hora FROM horas
    JOIN reservas ON reservas.hora != horas.id
    WHERE id_doctor =  2 AND fecha = '2019-07-21'
```

Respuesta:

```
   hora    
 --------
  08:00   
  09:00  
  10:00   
  11:00   
  12:00   
  14:00
```

El resultado sería todas las horas ya que en la reserva con id 3 no coincide las 8:00, pero en la id 4 no coincide las 9:00, con lo que seguirias teniendo el mismo problema. Si haces el SELECT sin el distinct se entiende mejor al ver que horas se repiten y cuáles no. En el caso de consultar las horas ocupadas si que funcionaría bien.

Para obtener las horas libres se me ocurre que puedes utilizar un HAVING COUNT(*) igualado al número de reservas que existen.

```
SELECT DISTINCT horas.hora, count(*) FROM horas
    JOIN reservas ON reservas.hora != horas.id
    WHERE id_doctor =  2 AND fecha = '2019-07-21' GROUP BY hora HAVING COUNT(*) = 2
```

Resultado:

```
  hora    count(*)  
 ------  ---------  
  10:00      2    
  11:00      2   
  12:00      2   
  14:00      2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
"SELECT DISTINCT * FROM horarios_atencion WHERE horarios_atencion.id <> ALL 
                            (SELECT reservas.hora FROM reservas WHERE reservas.fecha = '11/4/2020' and reservas.id_doc = '45') 
                            AND horarios_atencion.id <> ALL (SELECT disponibilidad_2.h1 FROM disponibilidad_2 WHERE disponibilidad_2.id_doc ='45')";
```

Lo resolví de esta manera; selecciono de la tabla horarios de atención todos los horarios diferentes a los que ya están reservados en la tabla reservas y además selecciono en otra tabla los horarios no disponibles de cada doctor.

1) lee los horarios no disponibles de cada doctor.
2) lee los horarios ya reservados.
3) ejecuta la primera consulta y busca en la tabla horarios todos los que sean diferentes a lo encontrados en las 2 subconsultas. esos los muestro activos.

Después tengo otra consulta que muestra los horarios no disponibles.

saludos espero que le sirva a alguien!